# Wanted to know favorite play list songs of end users, should be on server or client side(sqlite) iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Actually i am developing an app like net flix and in that i need to save favorite songs of end user, i am playing http live streamed videos and also i need to save played time of an video so that end user would be able to play a song from where he has left this song rather then just play it again from beginning.

They are sending me url of streamed videos in following format
**http://xxxxxxxxxx/vod/*definsts*/mp4/low/mp4:1975010026_01.mp4/playlist.m3u8**

so my question is that 
**What should be the best option to save user's favorite songs according to streamed url**, means net flix kind of app having favorite songs in client side or at server side.what should be the preferred one and i am using MPMediaPlayerController from apple MoviePlayer sample app code.
If some one has any idea and want to know any thing more from my side then i will be available. I am and will be highly obliged for your any help. 
Sorry but my English is not good and i don't know how to play with words.
Any small help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably your best option here looks like server side;

Saving the Data When you are removed from the application should be ultimately dealt with on the execution of the app to close.

you have multiple options when doing server Side Calls, One i found to be the best is [ASIHTTPRequestDelegate](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h)

this has worked wonders and is fairly easy to learn.
You may even want to look into a REST method of pulling Video Feeds, may be a Faster and more secure approach.

hope this Helped! :)